# How to use django registration redux?

Tags: python, django, email, python-3.x

When I enter my email id in the registration form and submit it, I am redirected to a page saying check your email id. But I don't see any mail in my inbox. In the terminal the email is printed, which contains the activation link. Also, when I goto the activation link, it says your account is activated. Now I am able to logout. But I tried logging in, before logging out as well as after logging out. Both time I failed to log in. It says Please enter a correct username and password.
These are my settings. I tried in both modes - DEBUG = True and DEBUG = False.

```
ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN = True
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
REGISTRATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django Registration Test App]'
SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL = True
REGISTRATION_OPEN = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp-auth.iitb.ac.in'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='ngreloaded@iitb.ac.in'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='wrong.password'
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'ngreloaded@iitb.ac.in'
```

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't see any mail in my inbox. In the terminal the email is
>   printed, which contains the activation link.

That's because you have defined `EMAIL_BACKEND` in you settings. You have to remove or comment this line if you want to receive email to your inbox.

> Also, when I goto the activation link, it says your account is
>   activated. Now I am able to logout.

That's because you set `REGISTRATION_AUTO_LOGIN` to True. After activating the user there is a method `login_user` which will be called. In that method is a "hack for to bypassing authenticate()" which means that this method can log you in without knowing the password.

> But I tried logging in, before logging out as well as after logging
>   out. Both time I failed to log in. It says Please enter a correct
>   username and password.

Actually you have never defined your password. If there is no password field in your registration form, django will automatically create some random password during to process of creating a new user.

> These are my settings. I tried in both modes - DEBUG = True and DEBUG
>   = False.

DEBUG has nothing with your problem